# $D(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^3+y^3}$ verifies $\int_0^1 D(x,y) dx \leq c$

Tags: integration, bounds-of-integration

Let $D(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^3+y^3}$. In order to prove that the operator 
$$T_D : L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0,1), \quad f \mapsto T_Df(x)=\int_0^1 D(x,y)f(y)dy
$$
is bounded, I need to show that there exists some $c\geq 0$ such that for almost every $y \in (0,1)$ we have
$$
\int_0^1 D(x,y) dx \leq c.
$$
Solving this integral and finding directly a bound is turning out to be complicated. I would really appreciate any ideas to find a solution.

Comment: Substituting $z=\frac{x}{y}$, $\int_{0}^{1} D(x,y) dx =\int_{0}^{c} \frac{z}{z^3+1}=A(y)$, $c=\frac{1}{y}$, and $A(y \to 0)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{z}{z^3+1} ≈1.2092$. Also $A(y)$ is monotonously decreasing. So, $1.2092$ is the maximum value.

Comment: Thanks @AlapanDas; how do you know that $\int_0^\infty \frac{z}{z^3+1}dz \approx 1.2092$ ??

Comment: That is from Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that  $\frac{xy}{x^3+y^3}\,dx=\frac{(x/y)}{(x/y)^3+1}\cdot\frac{dx}{y}$.

Now since $y\neq 0$ we can let $u=x/y$ so that $du=dx/y:$

$$\int_0^1 D(x,y)\,dx =\int_0^{1/y} \frac{u}{u^3+1}\,du\le \int_0^\infty \frac{u}{u^3+1}\,du.$$

Clearly this integral converges since $$\int_1^\infty \frac{u}{u^3+1}\,du\le \int_1^\infty \frac{u}{u^3}\,du=1,$$ 
and similarly, $$\int_0^1 \frac{u}{u^3+1}du \le \int_0^1 \frac{u}{1} \,du=.5.$$

Therefore $c=1.5$ works, and it's relatively close to the sharp bound of approximately $1.2$ from the comments.

Comment: Beautiful!!!    Like this